# Как убрать пустые строки при запуске файла Python через code runner в VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

В терминале выводится вот так, очень неудобно из-за этих пустых строк почти во весь терминал.

[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Запуск Python нормально работает через просто расширение Python, code runner не нужен.